# GPIO access rights under Linux Debian buster in bash

Tags: linux, bash

sorry for the beginner's question, but I'm a bit stuck.

Debian Buster on an OrangePi Zero+

from root `# echo "6" > /sys/class/gpio/export`  works fine as root

the same line in an bash script executed as root fails w/ Permission denied

The script is `owner:root` mod is 2777

From user Level `$ sudo echo "6" > /sys/class/gpio/export` fails as well

I need to execute this statement w/in a shell script (can be root)! so what can I do?

Comment: There's an existing question: [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](/q/82256/4518341) Does that solve the problem? If not, I don't know why the script would fail. Please make a [mre] including the script and how you're calling it.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was found in CR/LF, imported from Windows. That's why it worked at cmd level and not in the script.